# SpriteSheets with XML and without XML

Tags: spritesheet, godot

I'm very new to game development, and I'm working with `Godot` engine. 
I'm making a platform game and I downloaded a package from the web with assets, it contained some sheets. 
I have used a 2D atlas importer in Godot before bt it requires a `.json` file which contains the coordinates. 
The sprite sheet i downloaded does not have a xml or json. 
How can i get sperate images from that sheet? Or any work around to make a tiled map in Godot?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Tiled Map Importer Extension](https://github.com/vnen/godot-tiled-importer) to import tile maps defined with the [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/).
[image: Tiled Map Importer Extension]

The extension handles both `tmx`(`xml`) and `json` files, and the editor can generate `tmx` files.

Comment: Yeah i have considered it. Bt wanted to build a map in Godot, I guess I'll do it in tiled map editor.

Comment: @Chronix01 The tool you use doesn't matter, the file it produces still gets used in the game.